# fetching data through model binding relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I was trying to get the user's photo *src* which is stored in the **photos** table and the photo id is stored in the **users**' table. My code -
I've written these lines in my User Model

**Model - User**

```
public function photo() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Photo::class);
}
```

and my code for printing the photo src -

```
Route::get("/photo",function() {
   
    $users = User::all();

    foreach($users as $user) {
        echo $user->photo->file . "<br>";
    }

});
```

It shows an error saying -
**Trying to get property 'file' of non-object**

On the other hand, I have the same relationship binding which works fine -
In the **User Model** -

```
public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

and for printing the role name of the user -

```
Route::get("/photo",function() {
    $users = User::all();
    foreach($users as $user) {
        echo $user->role->name . "<br>";
    }
});
```

**so if the role name is printing by this way why the photo src is not printing**

Comment: it might be because particular user doesnt have photo so better  access like this echo $user->photo->file??null. "<be>"; or echo isset($user->photo)?$user->photo->file:null . "<br>";

Comment: What John suggested, but Laravel has a helper function `optional` to achieve this. With that function, you should be doing this: `optional($user->photo)->file` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-optional

Comment: This would be a easy fix `echo @$user->photo->file . "<br>";` Or you can try also `(isset($user->role->name)) ? $user->role->name . "<br>" : null;`

Answer (score 1):

When you're using a Model relationship then you need to do it by calling it in your `User::all()->with()` method.

Whatever your relation may be it will be it's name will be called inside `with()` method in order to properly get the required data.

considering the relation ship is done properly you can do it like following:

**Model User** has the following relation with photos:

```
public function photo() {
    return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
}
```

**Model Photo** has the following relation with User.

```
public function user(){ 
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

After this, you can call it inside your **Controller**

```
public function get_photo(){
  $users = User::all()->with('photo');
  return view('example.blade.php,compact('users'));
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/photo',[Controller::class,'get_photo'])->name('get.photo');
```

**View**

Your view can have the foreach loop to iterate through photos

```
foreach($users as $user) {
        echo $user->photo->file . "<br>";
    }
```